# fwrite only works once in PHP

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm running into a strange problem migrating an app to a new LAMP server. I have a PHP script that writes multiple files each time it is executed. After numerous problems, I've written some code to test how `fwrite()` is working on this server.

Here is what I have found:

When executing the script with this code:

```
$fh=fopen($dir.'/log.txt','w');
fwrite($fh, $log);
f_close($fh);

$fh2=fopen('/tmp/log.txt','w');
fwrite($fh2, $log);
f_close($fh2);
```

A file called log.txt is created in `$dir` but not in `/tmp`

However, when executing this code:

```
//$fh=fopen($dir.'/log.txt','w');
//fwrite($fh, $log);
//f_close($fh);

$fh2=fopen('/tmp/log.txt','w');
fwrite($fh2, $log);
f_close($fh2);
```

the log.txt file IS created in `/tmp` (but, of course, NOT in `$dir`)

I've tried a few other iterations as well, and it appears that `fwrite()` (or perhaps `fopen()`) only works the first time it is invoked; it's ignored each subsequent time.

Any ideas or suggestions as to why this might be happening?

Comment: I assume u mean fclose instead of f_close?

Comment: is `f_close` a custom function? its probably that you mean `fclose`, and the reason the first one isn't making a file in `/tmp` is because of a fatal error

Comment: Try also to write some random output (like `echo "foo";`) between the first fclose and the second fopen, just to be sure that the script is still alive.

Comment: ah - random underscore. Sometimes after staring at code too long and messing with permissions and AppArmor you overlook the obvious. Using the correct close function - fclose() - fixes it. However, I'm using different handles ($fh,$fh2,$fh3) - i would have thought that even failing to close the previous handle wouldn't matter because each has a unique variable name. Not so?

Comment: No because it triggers a fatal error and halts the execution of your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function `f_close()` in, you probably meant to use [`fclose()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php).

And calling an undefined function results into fatal error and your script terminates (second block is never executed).

If you turn on logging/error displaying you should be able to see error message like:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function f_close() in script.php on line 123
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: Right, but this is writing to two different directories; the first is to $dir; the second to /tmp. So, if $dir = '/foo/bar', the code in the first block should write  /foo/bar/log.txt AND /tmp/log.txt, but the problem I'm having is it only writes /foo/bar/log.txt and skips /tmp/log.txt